# How do I use react-dnd to make draggable components and dropzones?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-dnd

I am creating a website with next.js, React, typescript and react-dnd. In it, I want block components that I drag from a sidebar and place into a list of drop zones. Here is my sidebar component:

```js
import React from "react";
import Block from "./block";
import blockData from "../data/blockData";

function SideBar() {
    return (
        <div className="h-screen w-[25vw] border-l-2 border-l-white absolute right-0 top-0 grid place-items-center overflow-y-scroll gap-4">
            {blockData.map((item) => <Block name={item.name} options={item.options} />)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SideBar;
```

Here is my block component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDrag, DndProvider } from "react-dnd";
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

interface props {
    name: String,
    options: String[]
}

function Block({ name, options }: props) {
    const [, dragRef] = useDrag(
        () => ({
            type: 'Block',
        }),
    )

    return (
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <div ref={dragRef} className="w-[21vw] h-[9vh] border-2 border-white rounded grid grid-cols-2 bg-teal-700">
                <h1 className="text-white text-lg">{name}</h1>
                <div className="grid grid-rows-2">{options.map((item) => <p className="text-white">{item}</p>)}</div>
            </div>
        </DndProvider>
    )
}

export default Block;
```

Here is my list component (it's actually just one drop zone) where the block will be placed:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd'

function List() {
    const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: 'Block'
    }))

    return (
        <div ref={drop} className="w-[23vw] h-[11vh] border-2 border-white rounded border-dashed grid place-items-center">Drop Zone</div>
    )
}

export default List;
```

For some reason, this code make the whole screen blank. I have determined (by commenting out code) that the problem is in the places I use `useDrag` and `useDrop`. When I comment them out, the website is displayed.